# Binding visibility to isChecked value of a checkbox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to bind my stackpanel's visibility to the checkbox's isChecked value. It's a common problem, but I just can't figure it out.

Converter:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <common:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

StackPanel I want to mess with(I removed some code, so don't you worry about listview's binding, I set it in c#):

```
<ListView x:Name="aktualniGracze" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel x:Name="stackLiczymy" Visibility="{Binding isChecked,  ElementName=czyLiczymy, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ileWypil}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

CheckBox:

```
 <CheckBox Name="czyLiczymy"/>
```

Nothing happens when I change the state of the checkbox, any clues?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do you see any binding errors in the output window? Set a breakpoint in the converter and see what values you're getting. Also, I'd change `isChecked` to `IsChecked`.

Comment: What's the DataContext of CheckBox?

Comment: Oh. Setting it to "IsChecked" did the job, stupid mistake, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you have your correct DataContext in CheckBox, I think you are just missing the DataContext.isChecked

```
<ListView x:Name="aktualniGracze" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel x:Name="stackLiczymy" Visibility="{Binding DataContext.isChecked,  ElementName=czyLiczymy, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ileWypil}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```